# "Visited" (consecutive days) in profile being reset

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

Has anyone experienced their "visited" portion of their profile on the parent site getting reset for no apparent reason.  I noticed this behaviour before, but I had assumed that I hadn't visited the site one day and it reset.  Yesterday it read that I had visited for 11 days in a row, but today, it was reset to 1.  The only thing that I know that happened between yesterday and today is that my internet provider did some maintainance on my system, but as far as I know, no cookies or other things were deleted.

Comment: I don't know if this is related, but I recently got a gold "fanatic" badge for visiting 100 consecutive days.  I'm pretty sure I didn't really do this.

Comment: still showing 1 day 18 hours after my last visit this am, so it should have rolled forward by now

Comment: Hey Dan, did you possibly visit from different computers, I have become suspicious of it resetting when I do that.

Comment: same here, but have been visiting most days for questions not badges. So where is platinum? ;)

Comment: I thought there was a  badge for 60 consecutive days. I am not seeing it now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whole days are measured midnight to midnight in GMT, not local time.  You might have visited early one evening (EST) and not visited again until later the next evening, thereby missing a day.

I'm not sure what constitutes a "visit".  I think that merely loading any page from the site is enough--you don't need any other interaction than that, it seems.

Comment: For closure, I suspect that Bill is correct, it appears that visits are measured using UTC (GMT) and an early visit followed by a late visit within a day accounts for the "missed" day for those of us in EST, so for those of us that are meso-nocturnal, this may be an ongoing issue but an interesting quirk of time-stamping.

Answer (score 3):

Days are measured in UTC. You must visit something other than the homepage at least once in 00:00 - 23:59 UTC.

Answer (score 1):

And non-trivial visit. A definition of no-trivial would be nice. I too have suspected my visits not being logged correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Never bothered watching it, as I know it won't ever pass 6 conservative days for me...

Hooray weekly no-technology day (or just plain religious).